# Specify encoding with libreoffice --convert-to csv

Tags: character-encoding, unicode, conversion, libreoffice

Excel files can be converted to CSV using:

```
$ libreoffice --convert-to csv --headless --outdir dir file.xlsx
```

Everything appears to work just fine. The encoding, though, is set to something wonky. Instead of a UTF-8 mdash (—) that I get if I do a "save as" manually from LibreOffice Calc, it gives me a \227 (�). Using *file* on the CSV gives me "Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with very long lines". So, two questions:

1. What on earth is happening here?
2. How do I tell libreoffice to convert to UTF-8?

The specific file that I'm trying to convert is [here](http://apps.gs1.org/GDD/Documents/All_GS1XMLCode_Lists_08December2015.xlsx).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Apparently LibreOffice tries to use ISO-8859-1 by default, which is causing the problem.
[In response to this bug report](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=36313), a new parameter `--infilter` has been added.  The following command produces [U+2014 em dash](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2014/index.htm):

```
libreoffice  --convert-to csv --infilter=CSV:44,34,76,1 --headless --outdir dir file.xlsx
```

I tested this with LO 5.0.3.2.  From the bug report, it looks like the earliest version containing this option is LO 4.4.

See also: https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/13008/how-do-i-specify-an-input-character-coding-for-a-convert-to-command-line-usage/

Comment: Thanks! Still no success though. With this command line: libreoffice --headless  --convert-to csv --infilter=CSV:44,34,76,1 file.xlsx --outdir dir; it's still got 0x97 for the em dash. I'm baffled. I'm running LO 
4.2.8.2 420m0(Build:2) on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: You probably need to upgrade to LO 4.4 or newer, as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: `loffice --convert-to xlsx --infilter=csv:44,34,76 input.csv` worked for me. [Reference](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Spreadsheets/Filter_Options).

Comment: Do you have a link where these `infilter` options are listed ? The link posted by @Adobe is long outdated.

Comment: `--infilter` seems to be about the input file and that would be why @Adobe 's command works (CSV input) and the OP's command (XLSX input) doesn't - just a guess

Answer (score 1):

You could try,

```
    $ libreoffice --convert-to \
    > csv:"Text - txt - csv (StarCalc)":"44,34,0,1,,0" \
    > --headless --outdir dir file.xlsx
```

[Here](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Spreadsheets/Filter_Options), you have a very detailed help about.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm still not getting it to accept the additional tokens. I've tried --convert-to "csv:Text - txt - csv (StarCalc):44,34,76,1,,0", --convert-to "csv:Text - txt - csv (StarCalc):44,34,76,1,1/2/2/2/3/2/4/2/5/2/6/2/7/2/8/2/9/1/10/3" and various other combinations. Any suggestions?

Comment: `csv:"Text - txt - csv (StarCalc)":"44,34,0,1,,0"`, csv`:`"double quoted"`:`"double quoted"

Comment: That's only going to be relative to the shell, but I tried it anyway with the same results.

Comment: [Here](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/21916/cli-convert-ods-to-csv-with-semicolon-as-delimiter/) are using `unoconv` and directly `soffice` for a related task,maybe could help.