# convert an excel file to pipe delimiter file in Linux using script

Tags: linux, pipe, csv, excel

Need to convert an excel file to pipe delimiter file in Linux using shell script. pls help

I'm new to shell script.
I saw a post to convert comma to pipe using the below code...

```
awk '{for(i=1; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub(",","|",$i)}1' FS=\" OFS= file
```

how to change this command for excel file to pipe?

Comment: Is it actually an excel file, with extension `xls`  or `xlsx`? Or a plain-text CSV file?

Comment: yes its an excel file with .xlsx extension

Comment: Then you can't use awk directly. You'll first have to get a CSV file using, for example, the command in https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/259361/70524

Comment: Protip: an `.xslx` is just a zip containing XMLs. Unzip, run awk over all XMLs, rezip should work. Atleast that's what I do with `python`

Comment: Excel should be able to export the file with whatever delimiter you'd want to use.

Comment: I got the CSV file now. Unfortunately our prod linux is on EL6 and GAWK ver 3.x. Below command is using FPAT which is availabe only in EL7 GAWK 4.x. so, pls help How to convert CSV file to Pipe delim file using GAWK 3.x?

gawk -v FPAT='[^,]*|"[^"]+"' -v OFS='|' '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$6,$7}' file

Answer (score 1):

I know this is is cheating but if you have gnumeric+ssconvert (my favorite *Linux excel*) you may

```
 ssconvert -O 'separator=| format=raw quoting-mode=never' in.xlsx out.txt
```

See also unoconv, and pandoc